# How to provide scope and custom components to netlify-cms-widget-mdx

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms, mdxjs

I've set up a Gatsby blog using Netlify CMS and added [`netlify-cms-widget-mdx`](https://github.com/karolis-sh/gatsby-mdx/tree/master/packages/netlify-cms-widget-mdx) to support `.mdx` files. I have some custom components that I've passed to the `MDXProvider` to make them globally available to all of my `.mdx` files without the need to import them in each file. How do I use these same components with `netlify-cms-widget-mdx` so that the components are rendered properly in preview mode in Netlify CMS? There's a code block in the [package's README](https://github.com/karolis-sh/gatsby-mdx/tree/master/packages/netlify-cms-widget-mdx) that I presume answers this question, but it doesn't say anywhere where I should put this code, let alone how I need to configure it the way I need to...any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to dig in the [Netlify's documentation about creating a custom CMS widgets](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/custom-widgets/) or in some [Netlify's articles](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/06/20/extending-netlify-cms-part-one-custom-widgets/). You need to create an isolated file where you will create your widget, let's say at `/src/cms/cms.js`:

```
import Trend from 'react-trend';
import { MdxControl, setupPreview } from 'netlify-cms-widget-mdx';
import Trend from 'react-trend';
import remarkEmojiPlugin from 'remark-emoji';

CMS.registerWidget(
  'mdx',
  MdxControl,
  setupPreview({
    components: {
      h1: ({ children, ...props }) => (
        <h1 style={{ color: 'tomato' }} {...props}>
          {children}
        </h1>
      ),
    },
    scope: {
      Layout: (props) => (
        <div
          style={{
            padding: '10px',
            border: '1px solid green',
            borderRadius: '5px',
          }}
          {...props}
        />
      ),
    },
    allowedImports: {
      'react-trend': {
        ImportDefault: Trend,
      },
    },
    mdPlugins: [remarkEmojiPlugin],
  })
);
```

Then, in the `/static/admin` folder, create an `index.html` that points that file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Content Manager</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./cms.css" />

</head>
<body>
  <script src="./cms.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Netlify's will infer that HTML and will get your new widget to the CMS.

Other resources:

- https://github.com/Benaiah/netlify-cms-presentations-example/ (author of the Netlify's article)